# Nested UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have an issue with UIScrollViews in IPhone. I have a subview child of another one. The father scrollview displays a ViewController that contains itself another scrollview.

If the scrollview child has 2 elements what I want to do is pass the scrollview events when the scrollview child is supose to bounce because there is no more content to be shown. Is that possible?

example:

scrollviewfather: 2 elements
scrollviewchild = 4 elements

Users scroll 4 times child a on the next scroll (cause there's no more content) the father will be scrolled!

any ideas? anything will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can set the scrollview scroll height width ..like this...

```
childScrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth*4,height);// control width and height
```

scrolling... here contentWidth * 4 because you have four contents...

hope its help you... GUD LUCK :)